# How to Add class new links to topmenu.phtml for Contacts page in Magento 1.9.2?

Tags: magento-1.9

How to Add class new links to topmenu.phtml for Contacts page in Magento 1.9.2?

```
<li><a href="<?php echo $this->getBaseURl() ?>contacts">CONTACTS</a></li>
```

Answer (score 2):

Hi follow belo code may be help you

```
<?php 
 $_currentUrl = Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl();
 $_homeUrl = Mage::helper('core/url')->getHomeUrl();
?>
<li class="level0 nav-1 level-top <?php if ($_currentUrl === $_homeUrl.'contacts'):?> active<?php endif;?>"><a href="<?php echo $this->getBaseURl() ?>contacts"><?php echo  $this->__('CONTACT US') ?></a></li>
```